# Order of elements in CharacterVector and NumericVector in rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I've got a `data.frame` extracted from a `list` (i.e. a `list` of `data.frame`s) and would like to read into a `vector` in Rcpp for further manipulation. Since all the elements are numeric, I firstly tried to read it as a `NumericVector`. However, the index was changed. Then, I tried to read it as `CharacterVector`, the original order preserved.

The original `data.frame` looks like this:

```
       0  1 18 19 31 Freq Prob
   1   1  3 10 10  1    6 0.12
   2   1  5  1  1  1    1 0.02
   3  10  3 10  8 10    2 0.04
   4  10  7 10  9 10    1 0.02
   5  10  9 10 10 10    2 0.04
   6   2  3  2  6  2    1 0.02
   7   3  3  2  2  3    1 0.02
```

Given as:

> structure(list(`0` = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1", 
>   "10", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"), class = "factor"), 
>       `1` = structure(c(4L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 10L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1", 
>       "10", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"), class = "factor"), 
>       `18` = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", 
>       "10", "2", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"), class = "factor"), 
>       `19` = structure(c(2L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 3L), .Label = c("1", 
>       "10", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"), class = "factor"), 
>       `31` = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1", 
>       "10", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"), class = "factor"), 
>       Freq = c(6L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), Prob = c(0.12, 0.02, 
>       0.04, 0.02, 0.04, 0.02, 0.02)), .Names = c("0", "1", "18", 
>   "19", "31", "Freq", "Prob"), row.names = c(NA, 7L), class = "data.frame")

Mode and class of each column are as follows:

```
   > sapply(Model[[1]], mode)
            0         1        18        19        31      Freq      Prob 
    "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" 
   > sapply(Model[[1]], class)
           0         1        18        19        31      Freq      Prob 
    "factor"  "factor"  "factor"  "factor"  "factor" "integer" "numeric"
```

Note: The first row is the column names listed in the `data.frame` and the second is the results of the apply function.

The `Rcpp` for reading it into `CharacterVector` and `NumericVector` is as follows:

```
  // [[Rcpp::export]]
  //x is the dataframe, idx is column to read      
  int dataframe1(DataFrame& x, int idx) { 
      Rcpp::CharacterVector columnChar = x[idx];
      Rcpp::NumericVector columnNum = x[idx];
      Rcpp::Rcout << columnChar << std::endl;
      Rcpp::Rcout << columnNum << std::endl;
      return (0);
  }
```

Output is as follows: say when index is 1 in R, i.e. 0 in Rcpp,

```
 dataframe1(Model[[1]],0)
 "1" "1" "10" "10" "10" "2" "3" "3" "3" "4" "4" "5" "5" "5" "6" "6" "6" "6"     "6" "7" "7" "7" "8" "8" "9"
 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 4 4 5 5 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 9 9 10
```

As you can see the order of the two vectors are different, the one for `NumericVector` has been ordered. But this only happens in the factor columns and no problem with the integer and numeric columns.

So the question is how to preserve the order when reading the factor into `NumericVector` in Rcpp?

thx

Comment: How about just one model? `dput(Model[[1]])`

Comment: Here it is, generated by dput(Model[[1]],file="Model1.txt"): [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-FaejLtF973bjJKTmtiNHdTcHM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The linked file is empty

Comment: file fixed [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-FaejLtF973ZzlKTWYtR1hpalk/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rcpp` has a limited internal representation of `factor`. Thus, you must pass in the integer value associated with each factor in advance.

This is the reason for the difference between:

```
Rcpp::Rcout << columnChar << std::endl; // reading from factor label
Rcpp::Rcout << columnNum << std::endl; // reading from id associated with factor label
```

### Edit

To understand what is happening consider:

```
set.seed(133)
x = sample(1:10, 10, replace = F)
x
```

Gives:

```
 [1]  6  8 10  3  2  4  7  9  5  1
```

This is purely numeric.

Now, consider a factor:

```
xf = factor(x, labels = 11:20)

xf
```

Giving:

```
[1] 16 18 20 13 12 14 17 19 15 11
Levels: 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Note: The value of `x` is no longer present. Instead it is masked by a mapping to a character value ranging from between 11 to 20. This is why you are seeing repeated 1s and 2s in the numeric output but 1 and 10 in the character output.

Next, if we cast as a numeric, we have:

```
as.numeric(xf)
```

Giving:

```
[1]  6  8 10  3  2  4  7  9  5  1
```

or the original values before "factorizing"

To get the actual level:

```
as.numeric(as.character(xf))
```

Returns:

```
[1] 16 18 20 13 12 14 17 19 15 11
```

### Edit 2:

To see this, let's modify the original function:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void dataframe_factors(Rcpp::DataFrame& x) { 
  Rcpp::CharacterVector factor_name = x[0];
  Rcpp::NumericVector factor_id = x[0];
  Rcpp::NumericVector numeric_val = x[1];
  Rcpp::Rcout << "FN: " << factor_name << std::endl;
  Rcpp::Rcout << "FID: " << factor_id << std::endl;

  // Numeric
  Rcpp::Rcout << "ORG: " << numeric_val << std::endl;

}


/*** R
set.seed(133)
x = sample(1:10, 10, replace = F)

xf = factor(x, labels = 11:20)

d = data.frame(xf, x)

dataframe_factors(d)
*/
```

Gives:

```
FN: "16" "18" "20" "13" "12" "14" "17" "19" "15" "11"
FID: 6 8 10 3 2 4 7 9 5 1
ORG: 6 8 10 3 2 4 7 9 5 1
```

Comment: Actually, I've created a dummy data frame with factor having no problem for the output ordering. I think it is the Model object problem. Could you show me explicitly how to pass the integer value with each factor?

Comment: You have to relabel the IDs associated with each factor before passing it into `Rcpp` or modify it within.

Comment: very clear, however, if the factor labels are 1:10 in your example. Then all the outputs (x, xf) should be the same. However, behavior of Model[[1]] is different.